# OpenSSH Disabling Diffie-Hellman (DHE) key exchange

Tags: openssh

I'm seeking to mitigate CVE-2002-20001 by disabling DHE key exchange through OpenSSH on an Ubuntu instance.

I understand this can be achieved through editing the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` at line

`KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256`

How might I edit this line to disable DHE key exchange? Will this be sufficient to mitigate the vulnerability? How can I make sure the threat is mitigated?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using version 20.04

Answer (score 4):

The `KexAlgorithms` configuration option is correct, but you want to use a `-` at the beginning of the line like:

`KexAlgorithms -diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group15-sha256,diffie-hellman-group15-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group17-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha512`

Because:

> If the specified list begins with a ‘-’ character, then the specified algorithms (including wildcards) will be removed from the default set instead of replacing them.

**Note:** you can wildcard this e.g. `KexAlgorithms -diffie-hellman-group*`

**NOTE2:** This doesn't work for older versions of `openssh`, on CentOS 7 for example the `-` doesn't work and you have to explicitly state what algorithms you want to use:
`KexAlgorithms  curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521`

You also want to control the number of unauthenticated connections with the following settings:

`MaxStartups 10:30:100`
`PerSourceMaxStartups 1`
`PerSourceNetBlockSize 32:128`

You can find a list of available KexAlgorithms using this command:
`sudo sshd -T |grep kexalgorithms`

Output before blocking Diffie-Hellman:

> kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256

and after:

> kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521

or you could us `nmap`:

`nmap --script ssh2-enum-algos -sV -p 22 localhost`

**References**
[dheater git repo](https://github.com/Balasys/dheater)
[sshd_config KexAlgorithms](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#KexAlgorithms)

Comment: The output of `ssh -Q kex` is the same before and after adding the `KexAlgorithms` configuration option and restarting the SSH service. Any idea why this may be the case?

Comment: @user281564 I've updated the post.  Using the `sshd` or `nmap` test provides an accurate output.  I don't have time to look but I'm guessing the `ssh -Q kex` command is what's available for ssh to use.  Not what's allowed by the sshd daemon.

Comment: I'm now able to verify that the configurations have taken effect. Thank you!

Comment: It's not the version of Linux that matters for the "algs minus" syntax, but the version of OpenSSH, see https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.5 -- and CentOS/RHEL7 packages OpenSSH 7.4, though with enough effort you could replace it

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085!  I updated the answer to reflect your feedback

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 20.04 you can limit the key exchange algorithms by setting the config item **KexAlgorithms** in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/ssh-audit_hardening.conf`. To avoid all Diffie-Hellman groups you could set:

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
```

There is an (updated) Python tool `ssh-audit` that checks sshd on a tcp socket. Its [hardening guide](https://www.sshaudit.com/hardening_guides.html#ubuntu_20_04_lts) advises to include a specific subset of the Diffie-Hellman groups:

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
```

To validate:

```
pip install ssh-audit
ssh-audit -l warn -p <port> <hostname>
```